# Advanced sql query

Tags: sql, alter-table

I have two tables in a sql database, I am trying to update a column from my committed table (committedtbl) with values from my vendor table (vendortbl) based on a common column from both tables.

There is a column with the vendor identification number (vendorno) in both tables, I tried adding the vendor description (vendorname) column from the vendortbl to the committedtbl but there are no values in it.

I need to insert values into the vendorname based on the corresponding numbers from vendorno... How do I accomplish this?

The vendorname column already exists in my committedtbl.

I have tried this, but got an error:

```
update v_vendorname
set v_vendorname = v_vendorno
from vendortbl vt
where v_vendorno = vt.v_venkey
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/). What DBMS are you using?

Comment: also show us what your tables look like with 1-3 example rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update committedtbl
set c.vendorname = v.vendorname
from committedtbl c
inner join vendortbl v on v.vendorno = c.vendorno
```